# Where is 'class' declared in Java?

Tags: java, class

In the package java.lang I see,

```
public final class Class<T> extends Object implements Serializable, GenericDeclaration, Type, AnnotatedElement
```

Where exactly is the 'class' (the word used after 'public final') defined so that it could be used to declare 'Class' (the name of the class in the above declaration)?

Comment: Could you clarify?  In all of this I'm left wondering, which way did you mean?  Did you mean "Where in the language specification is class defined?" or something else?

Comment: Yes, I meant to ask "where is class defined?".

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I'm trying to ferret out what you *mean* by that.  Do you mean that you would like to know where in a language spec it is?  In that case then @dystroy's answer is appropriate, but keep in mind that this is a pretty terse formalism....much as the BNF used by parser/scanners.  Or if instead you want an explanation for how to use the class keyword, such as found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html), then Raul's answer is appropriate.

Comment: Ok, except to be clear that the keyword "class" is not itself a type. It's a keyword used in the creation of classes, which are also referred to as class types.  Glad my answer helped.  If you like, please "accept" it officially as the answer.

Comment: dystroy wasn't giving information about uppercase `Class` (which is itself a class).  He was showing the structure of the language itself as defined by the spec.

Comment: As I wrote earlier "@dystroy answer which shows the syntax (for class declaration) ". I meant he was talking about class declaration instead of keyword 'class'.

Comment: To be clear though, that link to the java specification dystroy posted is what "defines" how (lowercase) `class` is used.  That's the language structure itself.  Both he and I had to guess at what you meant: It seems my guess was more on target, but it's still unclear.  Try to understand: `class` is not a type, as you put in your answer.  ***A*** class is (a class is a "class type").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Java keyword.  Simple as that.

It's not "defined" anywhere....it's part of the language itself.

Keep in mind that this answer is in response to your question below where you are asking about the *word* `class`.  Based on your subsequent comments to your question, you're not interested in the java specification's BNF style language formalism, so you're asking simply about the word:

> Where exactly is the 'class' (the word used after 'public final') defined so that it could be used to declare 'Class' (the name of the class in the above declaration)?

Comment: As I stated in the comments to your answer, I don't think using a BNF style formalism is going to answer the question.  If anything, [Raul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30262107/4229245) make the most sense.

Comment: @dystroy, please note the comment the OP made in his question.

Comment: @Rounak, it was rejected because you're misunderstanding what a type is.  The lowercase word "class" as you see it is not a type.  It's part of how you create a class, which *is* a type.  You're confusing a class with the *keyword* class.

Answer (score 5):

It's a keyword defined in the Java Specification: 
[8.1. Class Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1)

> NormalClassDeclaration: {ClassModifier} class Identifier
>   [TypeParameters] [Superclass] [Superinterfaces] ClassBody

Comment: Ugh.  Pseudo BNF?  That's a lot of unnecessary detail for such a simple question!

Comment: @tgm1024 SO isn't the place of vague chit-chat.

Comment: dystroy, that would include your response just now.  What I'm clearly saying is that OP really seems to be asking something much simpler.  I really don't think that he's asking for how the language structure formalism defines the usage of "class", do you?  But it is worth a clarification, so I asked him in comments above.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two things in Java by name `class`.**

**1)** (what you mentioned above) is a **class declaration** (itself) - as in [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html)

```
class MyClass {
    // field, constructor, and 
    // method declarations
}
```

**2)** We have a special **literal** by same name 'class' as well, and as I just found - these two are different things. First is `keyword`, second is a `literal`.

`class` literal ...from [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> Finally, there's also a special kind of literal called a class literal, formed by taking a type name and appending ".class"; for example, String.class. This refers to the object (of type Class) that represents the type itself.